# How to print a field in a view only when it appears first?

Tags: views, entities, taxonomy-terms

I have a View which lists products (nodes). In the View, I first display the taxonomy the node belongs to, and then the title and image of the product. I have ordered the query by taxonomy. The problem is that I get a repeated taxonomy for each row of the View (each product). How can I display the taxonomy just once, the first time it occurs, and then all the products belonging to that taxonomy, then another different taxonomy and its products and so on...

Now I have this result

```
Sports
    - The great book of soccer
Sports    
    - Practicing tennis
Sports 
    - Mastering Chess
Science
    - Quantum Mechanics
Science
    - Cold fusion
```

and I want this result

```
Sports
    - The great book of soccer    
    - Practicing tennis
    - Mastering Chess
Science
    - Quantum Mechanics
    - Cold fusion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the **Grouping field** setting in the view's Format settings. You will need to be using Fields (as opposed to Content) in the Format section of your view.

[image: Show Fields]

In your Fields list, click on the taxonomy term field to open the field configuration. Check **Exclude from display** and apply:

[image: Exclude image from display]

In the Format section of your view, click on the Format Settings.

[image: Open format settings]

The **Grouping field Nr. 1** select list is available in each Format type, so no worries if you have it set to HTML list or another format. Change the field from None to the taxonomy field you want to group by and apply.

[image: Grouping field settings]

Your view will now show products grouped by the taxonomy term. From this point you can use the Sort criteria of the view to get the ordering of products or taxonomy terms you need.

[image: Result of grouping]

Comment: You're quite welcome!